# PostgreSQL: Combine repeating window function (OVER / PARTITION BY) in one statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, partitioning, window-functions

I have a larger query in which I have to select either the first or the last value for multiple columns.

So far I have the below structure for my query which works as intended.
However, since I **have around 10 columns where for each of them I have to apply the same window function**, i.e. the `OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` part (like for the sample columns col4 to col7 below), I was wondering if there is a way to write this just once instead of having to repeat the same lines each time.

I tried `WINDOW w AS (...)` after the `FROM` clause and then refered to this via `OVER w AS ...` for each column but that didn't work.

Can anyone here help me with this ?

**My query structure (shortened):**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.col1
    , c.col2
    , c.col3
    , FIRST_VALUE(c.col4) OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY c.col1
            ORDER BY c.col1, c.col2, c.col3
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
        ) AS col4
    , LAST_VALUE(c.col5) OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY c.col1
            ORDER BY c.col1, c.col2, c.col3
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
        ) AS col5
    , LAST_VALUE(c.col6) OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY c.col1
            ORDER BY c.col1, c.col2, c.col3
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
        ) AS col6
    , FIRST_VALUE(c.col7) OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY c.col1
            ORDER BY c.col1, c.col2, c.col3
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
        ) AS col7
    /* ... */
FROM
    CUSTOMERS c
GROUP BY
    /* ... */
ORDER BY
    /* ... */
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this

Comment: Show the version of your query is the window clause.  It should work.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-select.html : `WINDOW` should come after the GROUP BY ... HAVING ...` clauses (but before the `ORDER BY ...`)

Comment: @wildplasser: Thanks for this comment ! That was the issue - I had put it before the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 4):

WINDOW should come **after** the `GROUP BY ... HAVING ...` clauses (but **before** the `ORDER BY ...`) , as described in [The Fine Manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-select.html)

This should probably work:

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.col1 , c.col2 , c.col3
    , FIRST_VALUE(c.col4) OVER www AS col4
    , LAST_VALUE(c.col5) OVER www AS col5
    , LAST_VALUE(c.col6) OVER www AS col6
    , FIRST_VALUE(c.col7) OVER www AS col7
    /* ... */
FROM
    CUSTOMERS c
GROUP BY 1,2,3
WINDOW www AS (PARTITION BY c.col1
            ORDER BY c.col1, c.col2, c.col3
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
        )
ORDER BY 1,2,3
        ;
```